# How to get and set the post tag value within WP Query from URL?

Tags: templates, tags

This is new grounds for me.  I'm on a hunt trying to figure out how can use a WPQuery to list all posts, that are filtered by the tag which the user clicked on.  So for example if the end-user is on one of my posts, and clicks on a tag that is part of that post, it goes to a new page with the following URL...

`http://pm.local:57786/tag/beaches/`

On that `beaches` page, I know from my child theme I can create a template called tag.php and build & brand the logic for that page. But from this same  tag.php template, how can WP Query list all posts that are associated to the tag `beaches` because its the value in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make a new `WP_Query` to display the posts in the requested tag (`beaches` in question), because when the page is requested, WordPress will parse the query args from the URL (or the rewrite rule that matches the URL *path*) and automatically make a `WP_Query` call which fetches the tag's posts from the database. And that query is called the "main query" which runs automatically on page load, **before** the template like `tag.php` or `single.php` is determined.

So in your tag template, you just need to display [the (main) loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/), or the posts for the main query, i.e. `while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); /* your code here; e.g. call the_title() */ }`.

However, if you wanted to know how to retrieve the current tag object (which is an instance of `WP_Term`), then use [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/). Or [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) to retrieve just the tag ID.

Or have I misread your question?

Comment: Many thanks Sally for the awesome insight into how all this works!  Much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like I have to relay on retrieving the slug through get_queried_object(), and use it as a custom argument for my loop, in order to see results.  I wonder if that is because I created a custom post type to begin with....

Comment: You don't have to make a custom query for that (unless of course if you are just displaying an additional posts section on the page). If you want the main loop/query to include posts in your CPT, then you could just use the [`pre_get_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) to modify the `post_type` arg for the main query.